# Karate - screenshot method throws a 'failed to get reply' exception

Tags: karate

I'm using Karate 1.1.0 and running tests that combine both **driver** and **robot** instances. The tests are passing locally, but fail intermittently when executed through Jenkins with the following error:

```
js failed:
>>>>
01: delay(20000).screenshot()
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: failed to get reply for: [id: 2052, sessionId: D9DA8BB2B46A340A64D04C96EDFC9231, method: Page.captureScreenshot]
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.sendAndWait(DevToolsDriver.java:161)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsMessage.send(DevToolsMessage.java:213)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsMessage.send(DevToolsMessage.java:209)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.screenshot(DevToolsDriver.java:823)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.screenshot(DevToolsDriver.java:801)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.Driver.screenshot(Driver.java:119)
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

In this particular example screenshot() call is 'ambiguous', but I've also tried it like so **driver.screenshot()**, which didn't make a difference:

```
js failed:
>>>>
01: driver.screenshot()
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: failed to get reply for: [id: 1832, sessionId: F7B7D4210527DE4B28FD2B85ACF66638, method: Page.captureScreenshot]
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.sendAndWait(DevToolsDriver.java:161)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsMessage.send(DevToolsMessage.java:213)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsMessage.send(DevToolsMessage.java:209)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.screenshot(DevToolsDriver.java:823)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.screenshot(DevToolsDriver.java:801)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.Driver.screenshot(Driver.java:119)
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

Chrome is not running in headless mode and in some runs screenshots get captured successfully. Some other things I tried are:

- changed the window size (**addOptions: ['--window-size=1920,1080']**);
- used **screenshotFull()**;
- increased timeout (**timeout: 90000**);
- increased Java heap space.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried to add code to alleviate this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/commit/8b6131ff8c05c3d7acce53ab826ba228e3ec03cc - it would be good to build from the `develop` branch and confirm

Comment: Terrific! Thanks for the quick turnaround, Peter! I just built it and will take it for a spin shortly. I'll report back if any issues come up.